# RegEx to find final occurance of a string in data

Tags: regex, text-extraction

I've been looking around for a similar example of this, but I haven't been able to make anything work quite right for my use-case.

I have a block of data that deals with user titles, and includes historical data.  For each user, depending on whether they've had a title change before, the data can have between 1 and maybe 10 occurrences, stacked up by date.  I need the most recent title, which seems to always be the one on the bottom, and is identified by whatever follows the string "customBusinessTitle="

Here's an example of what the data looks like:

> id=2039, employeeId=123, customEffectiveDate7=2018-02-22,
> customFINDepartment=Sales & Marketing, customBusinessTitle=Vice
> President, Communications, customTitleDetails=; id=2457,
> employeeId=123, customEffectiveDate7=2021-05-10,
> customFINDepartment=Communications, customBusinessTitle=Vice
> President, Communications, customTitleDetails=; id=5735,
> employeeId=123, customEffectiveDate7=2022-09-16,
> customFINDepartment=Communications, customBusinessTitle=Vice
> President, Communications, customTitleDetails=Vice President,
> Communications; id=7769, employeeId=123,
> customEffectiveDate7=2022-09-18, customFINDepartment=Communications,
> customBusinessTitle=Vice President, Communications,
> customTitleDetails=Vice President, Communications; id=9811,
> employeeId=123, customEffectiveDate7=2023-01-01,
> customFINDepartment=Communications, customBusinessTitle=Vice
> President, Communications, customTitleDetails=Vice President,
> Communications

My plan was to use the strings before and after the actual title information, to "bracket" what I need to extract - which in this case is "Vice President, Communications" as it appears between "customBusinessTitle=" and ", customTitleDetails", for the most recent (so final) occurrence in the data.

A couple of searches I've tried on https://regex101.com:

```
(?<=customBusinessTitle=)(.+)(?=, customTitleDetails)
```

- This seems to return the first occurrence only - this is similar, but I need the most recent title by date, which seems to be at the bottom.

```
(?<=customBusinessTitle=)([^,]*)(?:(?!.*customBusinessTitle=).)*(?<!, customTitleDetails=)
```

- I'm honestly a little confused about this one; it seems to return multiple occurrences of "Vice President" but cuts off ", Communications" (which I need), and then in the final occurrence, it matches everything from "customBusinessTitle" until the end of the line, which is MORE than I need.  I'm including it only because it does something different with the last occurrence.

```
(?<=customBusinessTitle=)([^,]*)(?:(?!.*customBusinessTitle=).)(?<!, customTitleDetails=)
```

- This one seems closest for what I need - it only returns the final occurrence, but it cuts off at the comma in the title, whereas I need it to capture the whole title.

I feel pretty close with that last one, but I can't quite see how to get it to include the whole title instead of only "Vice President" - Any advice?

Thanks for looking!!

**FINAL EDIT:**
Both @Bohemian and @David found workable solutions for this - thank you both, I wish I could mark more than one answer!

Thanks to everyone else who offered comments and suggestions as well, I appreciate you!

Comment: What language are you using? Most provide a way to return all the matches. Then you can just use the last element of that.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show 3 or 4 example strings and the output wanted from each.

Comment: @barmar  I'm actually stuck pulling this whole glob of data into our IDP tool, and then trying to set up some GUI-based automation to extract the title... so it's not really done through an ISE or a CMD window or anything, I'm kind of limited in how I can go about it.

Basically it's like selecting drop-downs that go "on each user, if their data glob contains 'customBusinessTitle" (which it always should), then "set title = " (and then I can stuff a RegEx statement into the line.

So I can't return all results, then use a 2nd function to return the final one - I have to "one and done" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=customBusinessTitle=)(?!.*customBusinessTitle=).*?(?=$|;|(, \w+=))
```

Some improvements to [@bohemian’s excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77108425): the end of the match can be any new key (`, \w+=`), the end of a group (`;`) or the end of the string (`$`).

- preceeded by `customBusinessTitle=` (positive lookbehind)
- and *not followed by* `customBusinessTitle=` (negative lookahead)
- match anything as few times as possible
- and followed by line end (`$`) or group end (`;`) or next key (`, \w+=`). (positive lookahead)

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/SPlJUU/1)**

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look ahead for `customBusinessTitle=` to ensure only the *last* occurrence is matched. Add look arounds to the front and back to match only your target:

```
(?<=customBusinessTitle=)(?!.*customBusinessTitle=).*?(?=, \w+=|;|$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ur4HanNQINFkgk).

Note: Answer adapted to cater for changes to question

Breakdown:

- `(?<=customBusinessTitle=)` the previous chars are `customBusinessTitle=`
- `(?!.*customBusinessTitle=)` the chars `customBusinessTitle=` are *not* found anywhere in the following input
- `.*?` match as little as possible
- `(?=, \w+=|;|$)` the following chars are either another field, a semi-colon or end of input

Answer (score 1):

In this approach:

```
(?<=customBusinessTitle=)(.+)(?=, customTitleDetails)
```

you could try anchoring the lookahead string to the end of the input. Off the top of my head:

```
(?<=customBusinessTitle=)(.+)(?=, customTitleDetails=[A-Za-z,]+$)
```

(I also thought of using some form of laziness at the end there: `customTitleDetails=.+?$`. This would still probably not work due to how regex matching is normally implemented)

**Edit** @Bohemian's approach is absolutely better, leaving this answer here just in case

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I need the most recent title, which seems to always be the one on the bottom, and is identified by whatever follows the string "customBusinessTitle=" ...*
>
> *... I need to extract - which in this case is "Vice President, Communications" as it appears between "customBusinessTitle=" and ", customTitleDetails", for the most recent (so final) occurrence in the data. ...'*

To capture this last occurrence, prefix the static text with `.+`.

```
.+customBusinessTitle=(.+), customTitleDetails=
```

```
Vice President, Communications
[Vendor] Senior Accounting Manager
Senior Information Technology Manager
Identity & Access Management Specialist
```